# Would this be considered duplication of validation logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have sample class like this

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

All of these fields are required before adding a customer to the database. So in the service/business logic layer I do validation for these 4 properties. I validate that FirstName and LastName are not empty and ContactNumber is greater than 0 and DateOfBirth is greater than 1930(just as an example). In the aspx page before I can pass the customer object to the service/business logic layer to validate and add to database, I do type checking for ContactNumber and DateOfBirth. I use simple functions like IsNumeric and IsDate.

I know the validation is supposed to be done in the service layer so that if another app needs to use this logic in the future duplication can be avoided.

Is it common to do type checking in the aspx page and then pass the object to the service layer which does all the other validation? I know one way to avoid this is to use javascript. For the sake of argument(never really happens) client turns off his javascript. Another option I was thinking about is the function that adds customer to the database accepts all its parameters as objects. This way type checking can be avoided in aspx page and just be done in service layer. But what if there are like 20 properties that I have send as method parameters?

Comment: It maybe not clear to me what kind of architecture you have but most of the time in this kind of architecture presentation layer (for example API) does input validation. Further in the line, API calls your business layer which does business validation

Comment: I'm using the 3 layer architecture. Data, Service, and View. All business validation happens in Service layer. The only thing I validate in the view is that the correct type is being passed to the business layer. To further add, I don't validate first name and last name in the view. I only validate contact number and date of birth to be the rights type values. But in the service layer I do validation for all the 4 fields.

Comment: What do you mean by saying View layer. If I understand correctly your Service layer does more than encapsulate business logic, it interacts with the Views and does all the business logic. You need a layer in between the service and the views, a layer that is responsible just for getting data from requests, passing them further and acting correctly after it finishes, either returns a view, a message to the view or something else

Comment: This is why DataAnnotations exist.

Comment: @DasBoot I'm working on webforms. You don't need a layer between service and view. I think you are referring to Controller in MVC.

Comment: @SILENT DataAnnotations use javascript internally. That's not the point of my question though. I'm asking more conceptually. I should have been more specific in my question...

Comment: Yes, I might have misread your question, didnt notice its specifically about webforms. Apology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really all depends on your design and needs. The points you mentioned are all valid points. Yes, ideally you need to do the validation in the service/business layer in case more than one presentation layer is calling it, but also because the service/business layer is the one that is responsible for the business logic.

However, you are also right that often some validation is done in the presentation layer for several reasons: It is the one interacting with the user and displaying the validation errors. Also some validation techniques can only be done in the presentation layer, example JavaScript which is used to make the validation much more responsive without a need for trips to the server every time. However, JavaScript validation is only used to enhanced the user experience, but never depend on it as a real validation because it is easy to bypass it.

So from the design perspective, your validation in the service/business layer and presentation layer is considered to be a good design and not bad duplication of efforts.

However, practice sometimes does not follow the theory exactly. For example, some validation could be very long and expensive to perform twice. In such a case, perhaps the only place you want to put such a validation is the service/business layer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be validating at both the client and the server.

The JavaScript validation would be performed on the client side and would reduce the number of round trips to the server if the user has simply made a mistake and forgotten to enter their details. This would also provide a better user experience.

The server side validation is crucial and should also be performed.  If the user ever disables JavaScript or an attacker sends malicious form values to your server then this validation would kick in. Since you are using `WebForms` you can use the Validation Controls within the framework, for example: `RegularExpressionValidator` and have a Validation Summary.

If you wanted to do the validation yourself then this logic would best sit in a ValidationService as you describe which could accept the `Customer` class as an argument rather than the 20 properties you stated in your question.

You may also want to consider using other libraries to prevent attacks such as XSS.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The way I have the validation setup to be is in the service layer. I have to do type checking in the aspx page because if I pass in a non numerical value for contanctnumber the page will bomb. The way I'm doing my validation, is that common practice?

Comment: @user3587180 - for this try and use the `RegularExpressionValidator` to ensure that the control has a valid numerical value for ContactNumber.  The regex would be something like: `^\d$`